# How can I change "next_billing_date" on PayPal Subscription?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, paypal

I would like to change the "next_billing_date" on subscription when the customer restart the subscription from suspended state.

The situation is (example):
Customer has monthly subscription, she pay every 2nd of the month and we deliver the product.

Customer Suspend the subscription....

When the customer resume the subscription she can set up a new delivery date. So we would like to change the "next_billing_date" in the agreement details to the (delivery date) - 1 day.
What I tried:

```
Agreement agreement = Agreement.Get(apiContext, formulate.SubscriptionId);
agreement.agreement_details.next_billing_date = string.Format("{0}Z", formulate.NextDeliveryDate.Value.AddHours(-16).ToString("s"));
PatchRequest pr = new PatchRequest()
{
     new Patch()
     {
        op = "replace",
        path = "/",
        value = new Plan() { description = "Restarting subscription (" + formulate.SubscriptionId.ToString() + ") - " + DateTime.Now.ToString() }
    }
};
agreement.Update(apiContext, pr);
agreement.ReActivate(apiContext, asd);
```

The PatchRequest is just dummy, because need a PatchRequest for the agreement.Update method.

I thought I can update the agreement this way, but unfortunately the "Next Payment Date" didn't change on the subscription. Everything else is fine.

Is anybody can help me what I should do?

Many thanks
Zoltan

Comment: Hmm, It seems nobody got excited about this question :(

Comment: I think, you can't change the next bolling date,

Comment: Thank you Harish, finally I could contact PayPal and they said the same.